# how to replace last occurrence of a word in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

for example:

```
var str="<br>hi<br>hi";
```

to replace the last(second) `<br>`,

to change into `"<br>hihi"`

I tried：

```
str.replace(/<br>(.*?)$/,\1);
```

but it's wrong. What's the right version?

Answer (score 13):

You can use the fact that quantifiers are greedy:

```
str.replace(/(.*)<br>/, "$1");
```

But the disadvantage is that it will cause backtracking.

Another solution would be to split up the string, put the last two elements together and then join the parts:

```
var parts = str.split("<br>");
if (parts.length > 1) {
    parts[parts.length - 2] += parts.pop();
}
str = parts.join("<br>");
```

Comment: `str.replace(/([\s\S]*)<br>/, "$1");` for multiline.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want this:

```
str.replace(/^(.*)<br>(.*?)$/, '$1$2')
```

This greedily matches everything from the start to a `<br>`, then a `<br>`, then ungreedily matches everything to the end.

Comment: Wouldnt you want it to be: str.replace(/^(.*)((<br>)*?)$/, '$1$2') so as to include the <br> in the last match?

Comment: The whole idea is to remove the last <br>

Answer (score -1):

```
String.prototype.replaceLast = function(what, replacement) { 
    return this.replace(new RegExp('^(.*)' + what + '(.*?)$'), '$1' + replacement + '$2');
}

str = str.replaceLast(what, replacement);
```

Comment: An answer solely consisting of code with no or little explanation makes it difficult to understand for future visitors which approach the asker should take and why your answer is viable. Please add explanations to your code.