# RegEx javascript, character whitespace round bracket

Tags: javascript, regex, character, parentheses

I have the following string in javascript:
"Hallo OR, I am OR )"
Note the space before the bracket.
I want to have this
"Hallo OR, I am )"
So basically just remove the last OR. I tried every RegEx combination without success, i.e.:

```
string = string .replace(/OR\s\)/, " )"); //NO
string = string .replace(/OR \)/, " )");  //NO
```

Removing the round bracket only works, but as soon as I add the OR, no luck

```
string = string .replace(/\)/, " )"); //Removes the bracket
string = string .replace(/\s\)/, " )"); //Removes the bracket and the space
```

I tried the RegEx /OR\s)/ at http://regexpal.com/ and it works nicely, so why not in javascript?
It feels like a very simple problem but after 2 hours I am still lost.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: String is a reserved keyword - although you are using lowercase. Make it a different variable name and your first attempt would work

Comment: When I type `"Hallo OR, I am OR )".replace(/OR\s\)/, " )");`, it returns `"Hallo OR, I am  )"` - which is correct(ish).  I'd replace with just the right paren.

Comment: Sorry for the 'string' Sudipta. In my code I am using an other variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string = string.replace(/(\s*OR)(?![\s\S]*OR)/,"");
```

See [Using Regex to replace last occurrence of a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744689/using-regex-to-replace-only-the-last-occurrence-of-a-pattern-with-js)

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
> s = "Hallo OR, I am OR )"
'Hallo OR, I am OR )'
> s.replace(/\bOR[\s)]+/g, ')')
'Hallo OR, I am )'
```

Comment: It will also remove both OR in the case `"Hallo OR , I am OR)"`.