# Removing one occurance of a sub string from a string using RegEx in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to replace last occurence of a word in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843049/how-to-replace-last-occurence-of-a-word-in-javascript)

I have a string, for example: "**345**,456,678,**345**,**345**,678343,232"

I need to remove the last occurring of **345** (in this example in the middle but can be nay where in the string) from the string. Thought about using RegEx but can't find the right pattern and couldn't find the solution anywhere.

Can any one help with this?

p.s. I know i can use JavaScript string manipulation for this, but I think that this is what RegEx for...

Thank you...
Erez

Comment: @Qtax: it is the same question, just different example content..look at the solutions provided, they are the same.

Comment: @Qtax What?  That linked question is about matching the last `<br>` in `<br>hi<br>hi`, not the last `hi`.  I don't see how `345$` has anything to do with it.

Comment: @Qtar yes I understand that the *example* is different. That is not what the definition of "duplicate" question means.

Comment: thank you guys, i was what trying it, and still not working for me...don't know why, I will add the Code example....Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified from the top answer of [how to replace last occurrence of a word in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843049/how-to-replace-last-occurence-of-a-word-in-javascript):

```
function removeLast(str, target) {
    return str.replace(new RegExp("(.*)"+target), "$1");
}
```

This uses the greediness of `.*` -- it will try to grab as much of the string as possible, including instances of the desired target, until it reaches the last instance of the target.  So, the whole regex matches the entire string up to and including the last instance of the larget, and then replaces it with the matched `(.*)` which is everything before the target string.

Comment: This is very close to what i used eventual....Thank you, My code:    .replace(new RegExp('(.*),' + lastCheckBoxChecked.getAttribute("value") + '(.*?)'), '$1$2')   and the value comes from the last check box that was checked.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this...

```
var str = "345,456,678,345,345,678,343,232",
    last_idx = str.lastIndexOf(345);

str = str.replace(/345/g, function(s, i) { return i === last_idx ? '' : s; });
```

---

As [@Crayon Violent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/184595/crayon-violent) pointed out, a regex should be built from the `RegExp` constructor if integrating a variable.

```
function removeLast(str, v) {
    var re = new RegExp(v, 'g'),
        last_idx = str.lastIndexOf(v);

    return str.replace(re, function(s, i) { return i === last_idx ? '' : s; });
}
```

---

If the value to be removed is a regex as a string, and it should be used for the `lastIndexOf`, then you can use `.exec()` instead.

```
function removeLast(str, v) {
    var re = new RegExp(v, 'g'),
        match,
        last_idx;

    while (match = re.exec(str))
        last_idx = re.lastIndex - match.length

    return str.replace(re, function(s, i) { return i === last_idx ? '' : s; });
}
```

But then if you're going to use `.exec()`, you could always just build the new string in the loop. You'll just need to be sure to exclude the last match after the loop is done.

Comment: only problem with this is i have a sneaking suspicion "345" probably needs to be variable, so you should tweak this to use an instantiated regex object where variable value can be used instead of a regex object literal added directly into `replace`, where variable can't be used