# How to replace the last occurence of } in a multiline string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

How to replace the last occurence of } in a multiline string in Javascript?

The method from [how to replace last occurrence of a word in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843049/how-to-replace-last-occurrence-of-a-word-in-javascript) doesn't work in the case of a multiline string:

```
"line1}hello\n}\nline2}abc".replace(/(.*)}/g, "$1");
// "line1hello\n\nline2abc"
```

because in this case every `}` is replaced, which I don't want.

Note: it's not a duplicate of [Replace last occurrence of character in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497318/replace-last-occurrence-of-character-in-string) because my question is specifically about multiline strings, and the linked question is not. Also not a duplicate of [How do I match any character across multiple lines in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159118/how-do-i-match-any-character-across-multiple-lines-in-a-regular-expression) because my question is about last occurence.

Comment: `"line1}hello\n}\nline2}abc".replace(/}([^}]*)$/, "$1");` perhaps?

Comment: Does it have to be with RegEx? Perhaps combine `String.lastIndexOf("}")` with `String.splice()`.

Comment: More compatible (pre ES2018) you could also [replace `([^]*)}` with `$1`](https://regex101.com/r/7xZyYb/1) (or instead of `[^]` use `[\s\S]` or `[\w\W]`...) - Makes sense where *single line flag* `s` is not supported)

Comment: @mykaf JS strings are immutable and therefore have no `.splice()` method.

Comment: "*my question is specifically about multiline strings, and the linked question is not.*" I don't see any such restriction. All the answers that do address the question (a couple seem to not) seem to work on multiline strings. Even [the only regex answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5497365) does work on multiline strings [remove version](https://jsbin.com/biwubuhito/1/edit?js,console) and [replace version](https://jsbin.com/pexojuxepi/1/edit?js,console) of the code.

Comment: @inSync, typo on my part. I meant `slice()`.

Comment: @VLAZ yes I confirm some of them "seem to not work", thus a dedicated question is interesting to avoid confusion about why it works in one case and not the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```js
const str = `line1}hello
}
line2}abc`;

const result = str.replace(/\}(?=[^}]*$)/, '');

console.log(result)
```

Regex explanation:

```
/\}(?=[^}]*$)/
```

- `/` - start delimiter
- `\}` - find literal closing curly brace
- `(?=[^}]*$)` - ahead of me is no other closing curly brace till the end of the **string** (not line)
- `/` - end delimiter
- Notice no flags; **important**

By not using the multiline flag `/m`, the `$` behaves as a end-of-string meta escape instead of end-of-line.

https://regex101.com/r/Ausg5r/1

Do note that PCRE has a dedicated meta escape for end-of-string `\z` but JS does not.

Comment: ...or `}(?!.*})` with the DOTALL (`s`) flag set. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FuJX7z/1). Note that there is no need to escape `'}'`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That's the beauty of regex, there's usually more than one way to achieve something =). As for not escaping `}`, my experience has taught me it's more beneficial for newbies who blindly copy others' regex to have special chars escaped because they don't know under what context escaping is required.

Comment: The counterargument to your second sentence is that anyone reading your code may erroneously conclude that `}` must be escaped.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Pick your poison. Either you have people benignly escaping closing curly braces or they don't escape them in a way which doesn't break the regex and lulls them into a false sense of success. I choose the former =)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to change the modifier from `g` (global) to `s` (single line):

```js
"line1}hello\n}\nline2}abc".replace(/(.*)}/s, "$1");
// "line1}hello\n}\nline2abc"
```

You don't need `g` at all since you want to perform a single match.
By default, the regex is performed per line, but using `s` will treat the input string as a single line.

Comment: This is simple and seems to work indeed. Do you know why it works, and why `g` didn't work? Maybe you can add this in the answer, I'll mark as accepted.

Comment: @Basj yes of course, I was writing my explanation, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/}(?=[^\n]*$)/gm` for remove `}` in every line.

```js
const str = "line1}hello\n}\nline2}abc";

const result = str.replace(/}(?![\s\S]*})/, '|');

console.log(result)
```

This regex works by looking for a `}` character that is not followed by another `}` character anywhere at the rest of the string.

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to replace the last `}` of *every* line, I only want to replace `}` once in the whole multiline string.

Comment: @Basj, sorry I misunderstood the question, I edited my answer with another solution besides AmyDev solution, and thanks for upvoting.